# Simplify Dynamic SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have written a Dynamic Pivot Table Query based on the following. Here is a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c985eb/2) for reference.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable1 ([idnumber] INT, [DataTypeId] INT)
GO
INSERT INTO TestTable1 
VALUES (1, 108), (1, 108), (1, 108), (2, 108), 
       (2, 108), (3, 108), (1, 109),(1, 109),
       (1, 110),(2, 110),(1, 111),(4, 108),(4, 108),
       (4, 110),(4, 111)
GO
```

Here is the Dynamic SQL that I wrote

```
DECLARE  @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@Cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
@ColsP NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @Cols = STUFF((select  ',  
ISNULL([' + CAST([DataTypeId] as varchar(10)) + '], 0) AS ''' + CAST([DataTypeId] as varchar(10)) + ''''
FROM 
(
SELECT [DataTypeId] FROM [TestTable1] 
GROUP BY [DataTypeId] 
HAVING [DataTypeId] <> '' 
) AS d
ORDER BY [DataTypeId] FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')

-- /////////////THIS IS WHAT I WANT REMOVED ////////////////////

SELECT @ColsP = STUFF((select  ',  
[' + CAST([DataTypeId] as varchar(10)) + ']'
FROM 
(
SELECT [DataTypeId] FROM [TestTable1] 
GROUP BY [DataTypeId] 
HAVING [DataTypeId] <> '' 
) AS d
ORDER BY [DataTypeId] FOR XML PATH(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,2,'')

-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SET @SQL = 'SELECT idnumber,' + @Cols + ' 
FROM 
(SELECT  idnumber, COUNT([DataTypeId]) AS Total, [DataTypeId] FROM [TestTable1] 
GROUP BY  idnumber, [DataTypeId] 
HAVING [DataTypeId] <> ''''
) p
PIVOT
(
SUM(Total) FOR [DataTypeId] IN (' + @ColsP + ')
) AS pvt 
ORDER BY pvt.idnumber'


-- print @SQL 
EXECUTE( @SQL)
```

I get the result that I want:

```
| IDNUMBER | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 |
|----------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|        1 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   1 |
|        2 |   2 |   0 |   1 |   0 |
|        3 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|        4 |   2 |   0 |   1 |   1 |
```

But I am sure it can be done better. I would like to remove where I populate the variable `@ColsP` - `SELECT @ColsP = STUFF((select...")`

There should be a way where I can create this dynamic code with just one loop through `TestTable1`.  As you can see, I loop through it twice.  Once to read what columns to create for the select statement, and once for the PIVOT table.

Here is the code that is generated by the Dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT idnumber, 
  ISNULL([108], 0) AS '108',  
  ISNULL([109], 0) AS '109',  
  ISNULL([110], 0) AS '110',  
  ISNULL([111], 0) AS '111' 
FROM 
(
   SELECT  idnumber, COUNT([DataTypeId]) AS Total, [DataTypeId] 
   FROM [TestTable2] 
   GROUP BY  idnumber, [DataTypeId] 
   HAVING [DataTypeId] <> ''
) p
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Total) FOR [DataTypeId] IN ([108], [109], [110], [111])
) AS pvt 
ORDER BY pvt.idnumber
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  I am not defining a SP, or Function here.  Simply a sql query at this time.  Thamks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your code considerably.  First, you can just use `count` to aggregate the data in the PIVOT.  There is no need for the inner count to aggregate the data or the `HAVING` clause. Finally, you only need to create the list of columns once. You could easily improve the code to:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DataTypeId) 
                    from TestTable1
                    group by DataTypeId
                    order by DataTypeId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
      = N'SELECT idnumber, ' + @cols + N' 
          from 
          (
            select idnumber, DataTypeId
            from TestTable1
          ) x
          pivot 
          (
            count(DataTypeId)
            for DataTypeId in (' + @cols + N')
          ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c985eb/8).  This gives the same result:

```
| IDNUMBER | 108 | 109 | 110 | 111 |
|----------|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|        1 |   3 |   2 |   1 |   1 |
|        2 |   2 |   0 |   1 |   0 |
|        3 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|        4 |   2 |   0 |   1 |   1 |
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Even better...  The only addition made to this code is: In the first SELECT statement, I added: " HAVING DataTypeId <> '' "  my live data set does have fields with empty strings, creating an extra column of 'empty' (which of course cannot be filled...), Thanks

Comment: @user3204669 You can use `WHERE DataTypeID <> ''` instead. `HAVING` would be used for aggregation filtering.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing it with this.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTable1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TestTable1
GO

CREATE TABLE TestTable1 ([idnumber] INT, [DataTypeId] INT)
GO

INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES 
(1, 108),(1, 108),(1, 108),(2, 108),(2, 108),
(3, 108),(1, 109),(1, 109),(1, 110),(2, 110),
(1, 111),(4, 108),(4, 108),(4, 110),(4, 111)

DECLARE
    @AllColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @AllColumns = ''

SELECT @AllColumns = @AllColumns +
  '[' + CAST(DataTypeId as NVARCHAR)+'],' 
FROM TestTable1
GROUP BY DataTypeId


SET @AllColumns = LEFT(@AllColumns,LEN(@AllColumns)-1)
PRINT @AllColumns
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something from your post.  Seeing how I am dynamically creating the columns for the a new query, the columns of the table ('TestTable1') are not really used.  They are 'idnumber' and 'DataTypeId'.   What I need is a non-query, non-loop way of getting what is populated into "@ColsP" (Which is: "[108],  
[109],  
[110],  
[111]").  Thanks.

Comment: My apologies even tho the technique is the same this is the correct way of doing it(i edited my answer).

Comment: Hello, and thank you.  This is really good code.  This indeed returns the column names of a table.  I will see if I can incorporate this.  Thanks.