# Using Pivot with Join Without Summarizing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this 3 table in SQL (version 2008 R2)

```
Table student
student_id | student_name|
--------------------------
1          | john        |
2          | robert      |
3          | jenna       |
...        | ...         |


Table subject
subject_id|subject_name |
-------------------------
1         |Mathematics  |
2         |Biology      |

table score
student_id|subject_id|score|
----------------------------
1         |1         |10   |
1         |2         |8    |
2         |1         |6    |
2         |2         |6    |
3         |1         |8    |
3         |2         |6    |
```

I've made a query that produce a view like this

```
student_name|subject_name|score|
--------------------------------
John        |Mathematics |10   |
John        |Biology     |8    |
Robert      |Mathematics |6    |
Robert      |Biology     |6    |
Jenna       |Mathematics |8    |
Jenna       |Biology     |6    |
...         |...         |...  |
```

But actually, I wanted this view

```
subject_name|John|Robert|Jenna|...
-------------------------------
Mathematics |  10|     6|    8|...
Biology     |   8|     6|    6|...
```

Note: the table is dynamic, the number of the student could be more than 3.
I'm trying to use pivot in the query but always produce error. Please help. I'm stuck on this. And thanks.

Comment: Post the pivot query

Comment: If the number of students and the names are not known then you're off to dynamic SQL, maybe start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389532/simplify-dynamic-sql-pivot-table

Comment: I'm trying to search in over 30 similar question from this site, but couldn't find the link that you gave. Yes that's my solution. Thanks @NickyvV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do Pivot in two ways.

**1. Static Pivot**

You should do this when the count of columns or the column names is known in advance(ie, in you case `Jenna,John,Robert`.

```
SELECT subject_name,[John],[Robert],[Jenna] 
FROM 
 (
    SELECT student_name,subject_name,score                
    FROM #TEMP
 ) x
 PIVOT 
 (
     MIN(score)
     FOR student_name IN ([Jenna],[John],[Robert])
) p
ORDER BY subject_name
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/282745/pivot-with-names) to view result**

**2. Dynamic pivot**

Sometimes the number of columns or values in `student_name` will not be known in advance. In such case you need to use dynamic pivot.

For that first of all, you need to hold the values in `student_name` in a variable.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + student_name + ']', '[' + student_name + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT student_name FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY student_name
```

Then apply pivot query. I have written the logic inside

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- This outer query forms your pivoted result
             SELECT * FROM 
             (
                -- Source data for pivoting
                SELECT student_name,subject_name,score                
                FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
                 MIN(score)
                 -- Get the names from the @cols variable to show as column
                 FOR student_name IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY subject_name;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/282754) to view result**

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is what I'm looking for. Once again, thank you for saving my day.

Comment: Welcome @afrizal yusren