# How to merge and count per column in a pivot table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, database

I have a view with Columns:
WeekNo, MerchantId, Transactions

With a Select Query let's say that we have the following results:

```
TrnWeek AgencyId    WeeklyTrn
1   110008  1
2   110008  2
3   110008  2
1   110045  4
3   110065  4
3   110124  1
1   110153  1
1   110155  3
2   110163  1
2   110165  1
```

making a pivot (stored procedure which creates dynamically the columns) i get the TrnWeek as Columns and as a result the following:

```
[1] [2] [3]
1   1   1
1   0   0
1   0   0
1   0   0
0   1   1
0   1   0
0   0   1
```

what I want to get is a "matrix" as follows:

```
TrnWeek    1    2   3
   1       4    1   1
   2       0    2   1
   3       0    0   1
```

ih which i calculate how many merchants performed a transaction in the first week (position:  1,1), how many of them performed a transaction in the second one (position:  1,2), how many performed their first transaction in 2nd week (position: 2,2) etc.

Comment: What does (2,1) represent?

Comment: I can't figure out how you get to the result

Comment: @DhruvJoshi (1,2) will represent the value where first column row has value 1 combined with Column [2], which in that example has value 1 that position.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk the pivot is made using a stored procedure like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389532/simplify-dynamic-sql-pivot-table . I want to count each column based on all the other columns, in order to get in that example from 7x3 matrix a 3x3 matrix.