# Pivot Categorized data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a collection of data which has; A Category, A Date, a String and two values. A simplified example on how this data is below:

```
|  Category  |  TheDate  | TheString | TotalA | TotalB   |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  CatA      | 01/01/01  |  foo1     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 01/01/01  |  foo2     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 01/01/01  |  foo3     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 02/01/01  |  foo4     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 02/01/01  |  foo5     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 03/01/01  |  foo6     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatA      | 04/01/01  |  foo7     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatB      | 01/01/01  |  foo8     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatB      | 01/01/01  |  foo9     |  100    |  200    |
|  CatB      | 06/01/01  |  foo2     |  100    |  200    |
```

I want to Pivot this data so that it creates a table like below:

```
|  TheDate  | TotalAForCatA | TotalAForCatB | TotalBForCatA | ... |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|  01/01/01 |   300         |  200          |  600          | ... |
|  02/01/01 |   200         |  0            |  400          | ... |
|  03/01/01 |   100         |  0            |  200          | ... |
|  04/01/01 |   100         |  0            |  200          | ... |
|  06/01/01 |   0           |  100          |  0            | ... |
```

This would be a table grouped by the date, with each total being the sum of the values for each category.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Is this a fixed number of columns or can it be dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data sample

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Category varchar(4), TheDate datetime, TheString varchar(4), TotalA int, TotalB int)
go

INSERT INTO Table1
    (Category,TheDate, TheString, TotalA, TotalB)
VALUES
    ('CatA', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'foo1', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'foo2', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'foo3', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-02-01 00:00:00', 'foo4', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-02-01 00:00:00', 'foo5', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-03-01 00:00:00', 'foo6', 100, 200),
    ('CatA', '2001-04-01 00:00:00', 'foo7', 100, 200),
    ('CatB', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'foo8', 100, 200),
    ('CatB', '2001-01-01 00:00:00', 'foo9', 100, 200),
    ('CatB', '2001-06-01 00:00:00', 'foo2', 100, 200)
go
```

Conditional aggregation when all columns are known

```
select theDate, 
sum(case when category='CatA' then TotalA else 0 end) 'TotalAForCatA', 
sum(case when category='CatB' then TotalA else 0 end) 'TotalAForCatB',
sum(case when category='CatA' then TotalB else 0 end) 'TotalBForCatA', 
sum(case when category='CatB' then TotalB else 0 end) 'TotalBForCatB'
from table1
group by thedate
```

You could also use PIVOT when you know there are a fixed number of columns.

If columns vary, you need to create and execute a dynamic SQL script. See link below:

[Simplify Dynamic SQL Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389532/simplify-dynamic-sql-pivot-table)

Comment: There will be a fixed number of columns, would a pivot be faster than the above?